# How to execute Report in Dynamics CRM 2013 to generate PDF in Online mode and offline

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Could some one help me out !!!
I have got a custom button in the Entity Quote to generate a PDFs file from a report . 
It work perfectly if the CRM is on-line , but once I switch in to outlook as offline mode 
it is not working . Because it is not getting a Session id and Control Id

```
var pth="";
        if(IsOnline)
        {
        pth= Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/CRMReports/rsviewer/reportviewer.aspx";
        }
        else
        {
        pth= " http://localhost:2525/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx";
        }
        var retrieveEntityReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var Id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
        var quotationGUID = Id.replace('{', ""); //set this to selected quotation GUID
        quotationGUID = quotationGUID.replace('}', "");
        var reportName = "Quote"; //set this to the report you are trying to download
        var reportID = "6A39D18F-2EC6-E344-8986-F49D6765A723"; //set this to the guid of the report you are trying to download
        var rptPathString = ""; //set this to the CRMF_Filtered parameter
        var strParameterXML = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'><entity name='quote'><all-attributes /><filter type='and'><condition attribute='quoteid' operator='eq' uitype='quote' value='" + quotationGUID + "' /> </filter></entity></fetch>";
        retrieveEntityReq.open("POST", pth, false);
        retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");
        retrieveEntityReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        rptPathString = "id=%7B" + reportID + "%7D&uniquename=" + Xrm.Page.context.getOrgUniqueName() + "&iscustomreport=true&reportnameonsrs=&reportName=" +
        reportName + "&isScheduledReport=false&p:CRMAF_Filteredquote=" + strParameterXML;
        //remove the part starting from &p:salesorderid if your report has no parameters
        retrieveEntityReq.send(rptPathString);
        var x = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.indexOf("ReportSession=");
        var ret = new Array();
        ret[0] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 14, retrieveEntityReq.responseText.indexOf("&", x) - x - 14); //the session id
        x = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.indexOf("ControlID=");
        ret[1] = retrieveEntityReq.responseText.substr(x + 10, retrieveEntityReq.responseText.indexOf("&", x) - x - 10); //the control id

        return ret;
```

Comment: You should try to debug the script from within outlook, if you check in the advanced option of ie you should be able to open the debugger and see what is happens with your script.

Comment: Any update or solution for this problem??